# How to set default value to -1 in @html.dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

i have tried but failed. Please help me how to set selected value to -1 in @Html.Dropdownlistfor helper class in mvc

`@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AMGFilterList, new SelectList(Model.AMGFilterList, "Id", "Value"), "Select", new { @id = "aMGDD", style = "width:60px" })`

my default selected text in dropdown should be "Select" and its value should be -1.

Comment: The 3rd parameter add a label option `<option value>Select</option>`with a null value (the default behavior for validation). If you want `<option value="-1">Select</option>` then you need to generate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with that as your first item for use in the helper

Answer (score 2):

Hi here is how i did it in one Project :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AMGFilterList,                
                  new List<SelectListItem> { 
                       new SelectListItem { Value = "-1" , Text = "Select" }

                    },
                 new { @id = "aMGDD", style = "width:60px" })
```